# LaTeX throws error while I compile my glossary

Tags: glossaries

I want to make a glossary in LaTeX. 
I use the "glossaries" package, which is defined in the following package:

```
\usepackage[acronym, nomain]{glossaries}
```

I defined the following glossary in my LaTeX code.

```
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
...
\section*{Glossary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}
\newacronym{POC}{Proof of concept}{Basisimplementatie om aan te tonen dat de voorgestelde oplossing in de praktijk te gebruiken is.}
\newglossaryentry{Open source}{name={Open Source},
    description={Programmacode die toegankelijk is voor iedereen. Iedereen kan vrij deze code gebruiken, aanpassen, kopiëren,...}
\printglossaries
```

But when I compile my file to a PDFLaTeX, I get following error:

> ! File ended while scanning use
>   of \newglossaryentry.

My PDF won't be generated.

Comment: Not related to your error but did you know that the `nomain` option will get rid of the main glossary? This means that your entry defined using `\newglossaryentry` will go in the list of acronyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `}` missing at the end of the line starting with `description=`